# Want to buy Asus H81M-PLUS motherboard and i3-4150 CPU; how to make sure it'll work?

Tags: cpu, bios, updates, uefi, haswell

I want to buy an ASUS H81M-PLUS mainboard and an Intel i3-4150. The CPU is an Haswell Refresh CPU, but the mainboard needs a newer BIOS version to support the CPU. I expect it won't be shipped with the latest BIOS so I have to update the BIOS before the CPU works. How can I make sure it will work?

Comment: What have you tried? What happened then? What did you expect to happen at that point? What, *specifically,* do you need help with? (Asus is generally pretty good with documentation; I'm pretty sure my motherboard manual even explicitly spells out the steps to update the firmware.) There's a *huge* difference between "the computer won't turn on or let me enter the setup utility" and "the system doesn't allow use of all the specific capabilities of the CPU".

Comment: I corrected my question. I want to buy this CPU and mainboard. But I'm sure that ASUS won't ship mainboards with an up-to-date BIOS.
Before I can use the new PC, I had to update the BIOS to the latest version to get the CPU working.

Comment: I edited your question further to hopefully clarify what you are after. If you feel I changed the intent of your question, feel free to either [edit] further yourself, or roll back my edit (click the "edited ... ago" link and then "rollback" above the revision you wish to roll back to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that the only solutions are too either get your hands on a CPU that does work and use it to flash before installing the v2 chip, or to send it back to the manufacturer for a flash (they will usually do so, and I am pretty sure asus will). The motherboard cannot flash itself without a working CPU installed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you decided to buy this motherboard, but for anyone thinking about it, I purchased board with A G3258 cpu on 14th September (same Haswell family) and the board shipped with bios 805 or 806, booted fine with cpu and was able to flash bios to 2001, although not done any over clocking on it yet.